# List of space launch attempts & outcomes

Tags: launch, history, reference-request

Is there a current list of space launch attempts, and their outcomes? I'm not just looking for successful launches. I'm also looking to see scrubs and mission failures.

The list should include, at minimum:

- Information about the rocket type and configuration.

  - Example: Delta IV Medium+ (5,4)
- Information about the payload and mission.

  - Example: USA-244 (WGS-6), Military communications satellite, GTO
- Date and time of planned T-0 or launch window.
- Launch site name & location.
- Outcome of the launch attempt.

  - Mission success
  - Launch scrub
  - Mission failure during launch
  - Mission failure in space
  - Mission failure on return (if return was intended and failed)
- If mission/launch was unsuccessful, reason for failure/scrub.

  - Weather
  - Rocket failure/malfunction
  - Payload failure/malfunction
  - Human error

This idea initially came about out of an interest to compare the histories of different rockets, in terms of their technical reliability. That would require knowing all launch attempts, the rockets used in each, and whether any scrubs were caused by technical issues with the rocket as opposed to other factors. More information would also be interesting for other comparisons.

Comment: Are you also looking for info on scrubs caused by external sources, e.g. weather or range safety incursions? These are super common but don't really bear on launch vehicle reliability (except in a positive way, I suppose).

Comment: @RussellBorogove I did list weather as a cause for failure, so yes. The important things are for the list to be as comprehensive as possible, for the period and vehicles it covers, and to be as detailed as possible. That way the reader can make their own decisions about how to interpret the raw data, with minimal to no pre-processing (e.g.: exclusion or summation of information) done on it.

Comment: One could add to that list *landing* success, failure, not attempted. Applicable today for Falcon 9, X-37 and suborbital vehicles. And for spacecrafts Dragon and Soyuz.

Answer (score 3):

I think http://www.spacelaunchreport.com/ has the info you are looking for, but it may not be in a single report. I.e., you may have to dig around a bit on the site.

note: I am fairly sure it does not list every scrub.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Lots of good information there, but I'm not sure they've got what I'm looking for in particular. There are some "reliability reports" but not a whole lot of detailed information to explain how they determined reliability. That's why I'm looking for a list of each launch attempt with its outcome and (if appropriate) reason for failure - allow the reader to draw their own conclusions from the raw data.

Comment: The detail you seek on scrubs is in this document for STS.  I do not know if similarly detailed history is available for other vehicles.  http://www.jsc.nasa.gov/history/reference/TM-2011-216142.pdf

Comment: Lots and lots of soviet scrubbed missions are still classified.

Answer (score 3):

[There's one for SpaceX here](http://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=36507.0). SpaceX has been under a great deal more scrutiny than other launch providers; most of the time people simply do not care enough about launch scrubs to put them in a list, since what's more important is a successful launch.

I suspect that to compile a similar list would involve combing through decades' worth of individual reports on launches, and even then uncertainty about whether or not reports simply didn't bother to mention any launch holds or scrubs would be very high.

The link to the PDF in the previous comment of the Shuttle missions summary does include the number of scrubs per mission, though the document is 300 pages long and it would take some time to go through that.

Comment: One should note that Falcon 9 is a rocket under continuous development, so history is less reliable to extrapolate from. For example, v1.1 is 50% heavier at launch than v1.0 and the next one to launch is v1.2.